# BoxShadow of the <th> tags is not continuously

Tags: html, css

i started with tables today and stumbled across many problems. The main thing i try to do is a table, with border-radius and a border + box-shadow beneath the th-row.

First thing i tried was using the border-collapse: collapse property. 
But after using this, it was not possible to give the table a border-radius with CSS only. So i didn't consider that as an option.

Since the tr-tag doesn't seem to work with the border and box-shadow attribute, i had to use every single th-tag. But after doing this, i have weird white spaces between every th-tag (marked in red). The Border itself is fine, but the box-shadow has those weird white spaces.

[image: This is a picture of the problem:]

Here is the HTML Code(Just 2 Rows instead of all the 16 :D):

```
<table class="VitaTable">
 <tr>
  <th class="VitaTableHeaderL">Jahr</th>
  <th class="VitaTableHeader">Titel</th>
  <th class="VitaTableHeader">Rolle</th>
  <th class="VitaTableHeader">Regie</th>
  <th class="VitaTableHeader">Sender</th>
  <th class="VitaTableHeaderR"> . </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="VitaTableInfoL">2018</td>
  <td class="VitaTableInfo">Broadcast Yourself</td>
  <td class="VitaTableInfo">(HR) Michael Grünewald</td>
  <td class="VitaTableInfo">Manuel Eglhofer</td>
  <td class="VitaTableInfo">Hochschule Ansbach</td>
  <td class="VitaTableInfoR"><a href="https://website.com" alt="Videotitel"><img class="VitaPlaybutton" src="Picture></a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="VitaTableInfoL">2018</td>
  <td class="VitaTableInfo">Crossroads</td>
  <td class="VitaTableInfo">(HR) Jonas Hartmann</td>
  <td class="VitaTableInfo">Hannes Müller</td>
  <td class="VitaTableInfo">Hochschule Ansbach</td>
  <td class="VitaTableInfoR"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Im using classes because i might want to do another table, looking completely different. Here is the CSS:

```
/* Table */
table.VitaTable {
  border: 1px solid #424242;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px #e4e4e4;
}

/* Header*/

th.VitaTableHeaderL {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #424242;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 3px -3px #e4e4e4;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 12px;
}

th.VitaTableHeader {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #424242;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 3px -3px #e4e4e4;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

th.VitaTableHeaderR {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #424242;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 3px -3px #e4e4e4;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

/* Info */

td.VitaTableInfoL {
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  padding-left: 12px;
}

td.VitaTableInfo {
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}

td.VitaTableInfoR {
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

.VitaPlaybutton {
  width: 20px;
}
```

Is there an easy solution i overlooked? I would appreciate any hint and thanks a lot in advance. :)

Comment: If you could provide a working code sample over an image this will be a lot easier to answer. You could have many things going on in that image that isn't represented in the code pasted here.

Comment: Whats the matter? That Code i posted is pretty much it. Maybe i can provide the things you need if you exactly tell me what you need :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `spread-radius` has a negative value so it's pulling the shadow in.

Your best bet would be to add a `thead` around the `th`'s and apply it to this or if you can't change the HTML structure then you could do:

```
table.VitaTable tr:first-chidild {
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 3px -3px #e4e4e4;
}
```

Then remove the `box-shadow` from all of the `th`'s

[JSFiddle showing the `thead` approach](https://jsfiddle.net/8o4rq9n6/8/)

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help! :) so i pasted the following CSS:
    table.VitaTable tr:first-child {
      box-shadow: 0px 6px 3px -3px #e4e4e4;
    }

and added a 

    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Test</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>

around the header of the table. However this does not seem to work :( 
Did i do anything wrong?

Comment: @AlphaLeviathan no worries! If this answered your question please mark it :)

Comment: edited my last post, just recognised that the enter key posts instead of breaking the line :D Maybe you can look at it :)

Comment: @AlphaLeviathan i've attached a JSFiddle showing you the working code based on your code example

Comment: thank you for your effort! But now the border-radius of the table does not work anymore :/

Comment: @AlphaLeviathan have updated the fiddle to add these back in.

Comment: maybe its just me being stupid, but i think the border-radius still does not work. As far as i know this property does not work with border-collapse: collapse :( It doesn't see to work in your fiddle as well.

Comment: If you check my updated fiddle it doesn't have the `border-collapse` on it anymore. *Edit* My bad i forgot to update it! The answer has the updated fiddle now.

Comment: Haha ok :D But now the box-shadow of the thead does not work anymore :(

Comment: Would you be able to point out which part isn't working? The thead in my example has the box shadow at the bottom of it

Comment: Well this is really weird. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like for me: https://imgur.com/a/CDoVkXg

Comment: That is weird, here is how it looks for me: https://i.imgur.com/r35ow8g.png. What browser are you using?

Comment: im using safari, in chrome it looks like yours. But even there are still those white spaces at the very left and right :/

Comment: You're not going to be able to avoid the negative spaces unfortunately as you're using `-3px` as your last value which pulls in the spread radius by `3px`

Comment: and there is no other way to get the box-shadow only on the bottom right? Well i guess ill have to do it with Divs and a lot of time then :/